# Groovy: How to check multiple tag value in xml?

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I  have  xml  content  like  this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><service>
  <rs>
    <Id>
      <details>
        <start>2017-10-07</start>
        <startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>
        <endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>
        <runAs>false</runAs>
        <makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
        <patch>this is  patch</patch>
        <parameter>1</parameter>
      </details>
    </Id>
    <person>
      <details>
        <start>2017-09-07</start>
        <startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>
        <endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>
        <runAs>true</runAs>
        <makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
        <patch>this is  patch</patch>
        <parameter>1</parameter>
      </details>
    </person>
  </rs>
  <country>
  <details>
        <start>2017-09-07</start>
        <startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>
        <endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>
        <runAs>true</runAs>
        <makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
        <patch>this is  patch</patch>
        <parameter>1</parameter>
      </details>
  </country>
</service>
```

and  i  want to   check   each start tag value  and  then  update  value of  runAs i  have tried  this :

```
  def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(content)
            def start=xml.'**'.details.start[0].text();
            def  run=xml.'**'.details.start[0].text();
            if(start!=currentDate &&  run!='false'){

                xml.'**'.details.runAs[0].value="false";
            }
           else {
                xml.'**'.details.find({p->

                    p.start[0].value= subtractDays(p.start[0].text(),p.parameter[0].text()).toString()
                    p.runAs[0].value='false';
                })


            }
            def newxml=XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

But it has updated only rs->Id->details->runAs  value,  what  should  I change   to update every  `runAs`  tag  value and  in certain case  update every  start  tag values too?

Comment: When do you want to change `start` element value? Looks `runAs` to be false always, right?

Comment: I want  to  update  start   when  it  it is  equal  to  current  day, no   runAs   isn't   always  false

Comment: What do you want to update with for start when it is not equal? Basically you got the idea, right?

Comment: i want  to  subtract day  and  update  this  value   as  as  start  and  also set  relative   runAs  value  to  true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the `runAs` element value to `false` using below code:

```
//Pass xml as string to parseText method
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
//Find runAs element and change value to false
xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'runAs'}.collect{it.replaceBody false}
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/UQnag7)</kbd>

In the same way, you can change the value of `start` element value as well by providing the condition in side `findAll` closure.

Comment: Can  i  use the  same  logic  for  expression  like  this    p.start[0].value= subtractDays(p.start[0].text(),p.parameter[0].text()).toString()

Comment: I mean Can i  check  if  it  is  nesseccary   to  change  start  and  then  change it